# Integrate Ok Google to open my music player application

Tags: android, google-voice-actions

I am creating a music player application and I want to open my application using **"OK Google"** command. I searched a lot but I can't find anything related to that. I also defined the voice action in the intent filter like below but that didn't helped either.

```
<activity
        android:name="com.demo.musicplayer.ActivityMusicPlayer"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:label="XPlayer">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VOICE_COMMAND"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

It always opens the google play music application whenever I try with the voice command. Also I can't find any option to set my app as default. I am testing in Android Oreo

Answer (score 1):

Well if you want an easier solution what you can do is say "ok google open 'myMusicApplication'" whatever the name of the application is

Then you can just say ok google unpause

I know it is kinda weird, but the phrase unpause is the only way to play music, because if you say play it'll suggest games for some reason.

ex:

> Ok Google. Open Spotify.
>
> Ok Google. Unpause.

this is the best way to go about this especially to be hands-free when driving and of course you can say

> Ok Google. Skip

to move on to the next song

Hope this makes it much easier for you than actually developing an app for this.

This method even works for the app I'm currently building. I told Google to open my app and it worked. Of it isn't working for you I suggest maybe addidn Google authentication to your app. Maybe that will make the difference for Google to find an open your app.

Comment: I am not developing app for this purpose. I am developing a music player application and want my music player to be opened with ok google command

Comment: Ah I see. But you still don't need to worry about integrating ok Google, because when you ask Google to open an app by name Google finds the app and opens it.

Comment: Well its not working for me. I read somewhere that for the above to happen your app should be available on play store

Comment: Oh yes. I forgot about that bit. When you ask it, google searches the play store and launches via the play store.

Comment: So you are saying that's not possible in debug app?

Comment: Maybe you need to add Google authentication to your app. It's super easy to do using the firebase authentication API!

Comment: Oh wait you know what actually. I think you just need to incorportaed Google services in your Gradle.

Comment: Ok I will try that

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm having the very same problem